# Prove that there exist infinitely many squares $a$ such that $\sqrt{\sqrt{a}}$ is a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was just thinking about squares while randomly punched numbers into my calculator and I was wondering do there exist infinitely many squares such that $\sqrt{\sqrt{a}}$ is a square and $a$ is also a square? For example:

$$\begin{array}{l|c}
a & \sqrt{\sqrt{a}} \\ \hline
256 & 4 \\
16 & 2 
\end{array}$$

I tried some numbers and it seemed to work for a couple but I want to prove that there are infinitely many of these. I am not well versed in proving (at all) so if someone could provide me with preliminary steps then that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Let $a=n^8, n=0,1,2...$.

Comment: @BarackObama That was a very helpful hint!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $\sqrt{\sqrt a}$ is a square itself then we can write it as $n^2$, therefore $a=\left(\left(n^2\right)^2\right)^2=n^8$.

From this it is easy to conclude the infinitude of these numbers.